# Selenium WebdriverJS Promise Loop

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, promise

I'm trying to look for the "More" link in a container to keep clicking on it until the link is no longer there. I'm creating a deferred and returning it with the fulfill call happening once there is no longer a "More" link available.

```
.then(function (previousResults) {
    var deferred = webdriver.promise.defer();

    // look for the more link, keep clicking it till it's no longer available
    browser.wait(function() {
        // see if we have "more" to click on
        browser.findElements(byMoreLinkXpath)
            .then(function (moreLinks) {
                if (moreLinks[0]) {
                    console.log('has more');
                    moreLinks[0].click()
                        .then(function() {
                            // check for spinner to go away
                            browser.wait(pageDoneLoading, configSetting.settings.testTimeoutMillis);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('no more');
                    deferred.fulfill(true);
                }
            });
    }, 5000);

    return deferred.promise;
})
```

Unfortunately, the promise is never fulfilled it simply times out. I tried doing a `return deferred.promise;` in the `else` block and while it works for `reject`, it still doesn't work for `fulfill`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the introductory paragraph.

Comment: Hi Roamer, I basically have a container with N items to start. There is a `More` link at the bottom of the N items. Upon clicking `More`, N more items will be added to the container. I want to keep clicking `More` until there are no more items from the server, at which point, the `More` link will be removed. When the `More` link is removed and I try to `fulfill` the promise, it never goes to the next `then` block.

Comment: These clicks, are they user clicks or javascript triggers?

Comment: Also, can we assume this is a monkey patch, which is the only scenario that makes sense?

Comment: If you see multiple 'no more' messages, then the issue is broader than the promise not being fulfilled. The overall process does not cease when the terminal condition is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax of `webdriver.wait`:

#### [wait(condition, opt_timeout, opt_message)](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#wait)

but in your code, the first argument is neither a `condition` nor a `promise` but a `function`, so I would change it to:

also, I think what you are doing here is promise anti-pattern( also I am not seeing the loop of checking again for more links, sorry but I think you do not completely understand `driver.wait` ), I would simply reduce the above function as:

```
function exhaustMoreLinks(){
    return driver.wait( until.elementLocated(byMoreLinkXpath), 5000)
        .then(function(){
            return driver.findElement(byMoreLinkXpath);
        }).then(function(moreLink){
            console.log('more links');
            return moreLink.click();
        }).then(function(){
                return browser.wait(pageDoneLoading(), configSetting.settings.testTimeoutMillis).then(exhaustMoreLinks);
            }, function(err){
            if(err.name === 'NoSuchElementError' || (err.message.search(/timed out/i)> -1 && err.message.search(/waiting element/i) > -1) ){    // checking if error because time-out or element not found, if true, redirect to fulfil
                console.log('no more links');
                return;
            }else{
                throw err;
            }
        });
}
```

and usage would be like:

```
...
.then(exhaustMoreLinks)
...
```

Comment: Yes, if `driver.wait()` and `browser.wait()` return promises then neither needs to be promisified and the code in the question is an example of the deferred anti-pattern. Presumably `driver.findElement()` and `moreLink.click()` also return promises?

Comment: Yep,  both do return promises

Comment: Thanks, mido22, your example with the recursion helped solved the issue for me.

Roamer, thanks for your comments too.